# What can a Menorah be made of?

Tags: halacha, chanuka, menora-chanukia

On Chanukkah we light candles/wicks every night. In my experience, those lights are always held in a special candelabra ("Menorah" or "Chanukiya") designated specifically for that purpose.

I'm not sure if such an object is required, but even if is not, it certainly seems to be sufficiently associated with the Mitzva action/item when used, that I'm curious if there are any restrictions on its design, particularly in terms of its material make up. Are there any [halachic](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/597/) limitations on materials that can be used ([l'chatchila](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/702/)) to make a Menorah for use on Chanukkah?

For example, can one use a Menorah made of ice? How about one of cans, potatoes, or bottles? Perhaps such items are too temporary or too disgraceful to be permitted for use in this context. What would the rules be?

Comment: the only limitation is earthenware which gets burnt and looks ugly

Comment: AFAIK, you can use anything, or even just bare candles.  Ice might melt too fast, posing both safety and kashrut problems.

Comment: @simchashatorah source?

Comment: Chabad on 5th Ave in Manhattan often has an ice menorah outside their building.  But no one is yotzei with that one, but it does look pretty.

Comment: I saw @simchashatorah's point in the Kitzur Shulchan Aruch. I would be surprised if it's not in earlier sources, too.

Comment: Are you assuming that it is necessary to have a menorah? if so consider editing in why you think so.

Comment: @mevaqesh Good point. The OP was unresponsive so I made something up to improve the question in response to your comment. Hod, please edit further as necessary, or flag these as obsolete if appropriate.

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/50661/759

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=50452&st=&pgnum=57

See note 132. Per Rabbeinu Yitzchok the son of the Raavad and the Chesed L'Avraham there are 15 types of Chanuka Menorahs and the order of preference is as follows.

1. Gold
2. Silver
3. Copper metal in the color of gold or other metal with such a color
4. Actual copper which is reddish
5. Metal which is called copper
6. Tin
7. Lead
8. Stone
9. Glass
10. Bone
11. Earthenware covered in lead
12. Earthenware (may be used for 1 year only)
13. Pomegranate shells
14. Coconut shells
15. Oak tree shells

However if you look in note 131 - even if all you have is oil and a wick you are Yotzei the Mitzva.

Comment: It sounds like he is just listing things that look nice for hiddur purposes.

Comment: As you can see from the last line in my answer anything is good, however the level of Hiddur is based on the list.

Answer (score 1):

From [here](http://www.aish.com/h/c/ht/48964931.html) it sounds like a menorah made of eggshells or hollowed-out vegetables is **not** permitted. The full quote:

> One may not use eggshells or hollowed-out vegetables to make the menorah, since this disgraces the mitzvah.

Otherwise:

> In order to enhance the mitzvah, one should try to obtain as beautiful a menorah as possible according to his ability. The order of preference for different materials is: silver, copper, other metals, glass, wood and china.
>
> [...]
>
> A menorah enhances the mitzvah but is not essential. A person wishing to light with oil could use several glasses or cups placed in a straight line. If candles are being used, they may be fixed in a row onto a tray or similar surface.

Comment: Whats their source?

Comment: @HodofHod I actually saw this offline in a sefer. Will have to look it up when I get a chance, and post that source. But I definitely have seen it.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Whenever you get a chances, I'd appreciate that.