# Is glazed porcelain considered earthenware or glass for building menorahs?

Tags: halacha, menora-chanukia

This is a more specific question related to the one of "[what can a menorah be made of?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/50663)"  Glazed porcelain has a layer of essentially what becomes glass after the glaze is fired.  Bare porcelain would of course be earthenware.   So, which category does glazed porcelain fall under?

Comment: What's the practical difference (*nafka mina*)?

Comment: earth absorbs water.  unglazed porcelain does that.  glass repels water.  glazed porcelain does that.

Comment: @Scimonster see http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/50663