# What does a Hanukkah oil lamp look like?

Tags: halacha, minhag, chanuka, menora-chanukia

Is there such a thing as a "correct" design or appearance for an oil lamp in the context of Hanukkah, whether prescribed by religious law, long tradition or any other metric? If so, what does one look like?

I've spent a bit of time looking into this now, and found a wide variety of oil lamp designs from ancient to modern, but no authoritative Hanukkah-specific design.

Comment: I'm sensing an oil lamp hat coming...

Comment: If you are looking for a recognizable image associated with Hanukkah, try something like https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Hanukiah.svg or https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Hanukkijja_messing.gif or https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/94/The_8th_Night.jpg . If this is a legal question about the minimum requirement for the lamp to fulfill the obligation, then there are very minimal rules allowing for much artistic leeway (most don't even require a lamp to hold the candle, see http://mi.yodeya.com/q/50708). See too https://enwp.org/Menorah_(Hanukkah)

Comment: @DoubleAA, or, for that matter, http://i.stack.imgur.com/GLR0Q.png, as adapted by WAF for [*Chanukah - Mi Yodeya?*](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1568/days-of-awe-mi-yodeya#3337).

Comment: @DoubleAA I expected someone to leave a comment like that, but within five minutes of me asking? I may have to scrap this plan...

Comment: @Pops shoulda used a sock-puppet, I guess.

Comment: @IsaacMoses I seriously did consider it! But I figured it probably wouldn't be necessary and I didn't want to deal with the hassle... shows what I know.

Comment: @Pops ever prepare a gift for a precocious kid who's too good a detective for his own good?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/50661

Comment: After doing some more research I think you're right and this is a duplicate after all. I didn't realize at first that I was asking about a menorah. After my initial search I thought I would be looking for a lamp with a single outlet for flame (something like [this](http://www.yeshshem.com/Images/oil-lamp.png)), which is probably due more to me not reading carefully than any bad sources.

Comment: Pops Such a lamp _would_ be kosher, as indicated above, but it's not so common nowadays to see that used, and it wouldn't be very recognizable as an image of the holiday. cc@msh210

Comment: Gotcha. I appreciate the suggestions but I was very intentionally trying to avoid a menorah or even a candle. Partially since we've done each of those before. I'm fine going with not-the-most-recognizable thing; if people see a hat and think "huh?" and then go to meta or Google and learn something, well, that makes me happy. (Plus isn't SE all about spreading knowledge?) I'll keep thinking!

Comment: @Pops If you're looking for other symbols of Hanukkah, consider the [latke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potato_pancake#Jewish_latke), [gelt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanukkah_gelt), [sufganiyah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sufganiyah), an [oil flask](https://market.marmelada.co.il/photos/458689.jpg) (in the story only [one flask was found](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanukkah#Traditional_view) and had to last for 8 days...), and of course, the [dreidel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dreidel).

Comment: @DoubleAA belated thanks for the suggestions! I actually settled on using a couple sufganiyot some hours before your comment, and then your comment made me really happy that I made a decent choice, but I felt like I couldn't/shouldn't say anything until the event started (which happened just now). For what it's worth, I thought of gelt first, but we used it last year (as earrings), and it turned out we did a dreidel in the very first Hat Dash, back when it was an Arqade-only special event.

Comment: @Pops Glad to be of assistance. Do I get a special secret reward hat? :)

Comment: @DoubleAA One invisible secret reward hat has been added to your inventory!

Comment: @Pops Not one shaped like an upside-down bathtub?

Comment: @DoubleAA that one... has a somewhat different requirement.